# Will Segoe UI work on Mac?

Tags: html, css, fonts

Is Segoe UI font built into the browser? If my visitors are viewing from Mac, will it work properly or do I have to set the CSS url for that? My designer says it will work only when we set the URL, however I removed the

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: "Segoe UI";
    src: url("fonts/Segoe UI.ttf") format("truetype");
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

and it still works atleast on Windows 7. I don't have Mac though, to test.

Comment: Your designer is correct, don't remove that code.

Comment: for anybody looking for a practical solution: You can use a font stack and use ["Open Sans"](http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Open+Sans) by Google as fallback. It is quite similar but there is no light version available.

Comment: @Towa Now Open Sans has all the font weights. `:)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will work on any computer with Office 2007, 2010, Vista or 7:

> The Segoe UI font family can be obtained as part of Microsoft Office 2007, Microsoft Office 2010, Windows Vista or Windows 7.

Will also work on XP if the user has downloaded a Windows Live package:

> Segoe UI is installed into Windows XP if the user installs Windows Live Messenger, or Windows Live Mail

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segoe)

For any computer that doesn't have the above, you will need to declare it with a `@font-face`

Comment: "will work on" is not the same as "is preinstalled on" or "comes with". Segoe will *work* on any system, *provided* the font file is installed or declared with a `@font-face`.

Comment: @BoltClock Always so picky with my answers :(

Comment: Heh, I didn't downvote it though! I don't know who did that :/

Comment: I downvoted. Segoe UI is not a free font, and it is wrong advice to say that one should or need to declare it with `@font-face`.

Comment: You can license Segoe from Ascender Corp.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela you can license it, and even if you couldn't we aren't here to argue legality, just how to do it..

Comment: @RyanMcDonough, there is nothing to argue about legality: either there is a license and you can show it, or there isn’t. And the advice “you will need to declare it” is wrong advice, as it presents something illegal as necessary.

Comment: I agree with @RyanMcDonough. It's not a bad thing to license a font and use it with font-face. Some people create fonts for a living.

Comment: For what it's worth, MS Office 2011 for Mac does *not* include Segoe UI.

Comment: Also, Microsoft doesn't even license it for use with a web-font.

Answer (score 19):

The Segoe UI font is not built into a browser. It is shipped with some Microsoft software. On a Mac, it is most probably not available, though a user might have acquired it separately or as part of some software package.

You should remove the `@font-face` rule and the font files uploaded onto a server. Segoe UI is protected by copyright, and it must not be used as a web font without permission from the copyright holder, Microsoft (which probably won’t give a permission).

You will need some other strategy, such as using another font either as the basic font or as a fallback font for visitors who don’t have Segoe UI in their systems. The [Google font](http://www.google.com/webfonts) Open Sans is rather similar to Segoe UI, and it’s free (and it comes in 10 styles, including Book, Normal, Semi-Bold, Bold, and Extra-Bold weight).

Comment: Lucida Grande is similar to Segoe UI and is preinstalled on all Macs (it's the default system font).

Comment: @daGUY, well, it’s similar to the extent that it’s of the same basic design approach (Humanist sans-serif). But more important that the level of similarity is the issue that using a web font (downloadable font), you would cover all systems, including Linux, old Windows systems, etc-

Comment: @RyanMcDonough, the URL refers to a page about Segoe UI Mono, which is a very different font, as you can see from the samples there (it’s a monospace font, as its real name suggests).

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add, that web-fonts (google fonts) are nowadays already a data-protection problem with EU-laws (as google safes some personal info), but the real problem with them is, that they cause time-lag on loading (0.6 seconds) and also cause a layout-shift (CLS) then.
I used web-fonts for 10 years. Now I go back to some pre-installed fonts...

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You may also want to provide the font in OTF as well.

You can find a list of available formats to provide the font in here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-webfonts/#font-reference

You can find a converter to turn TTF into the varieties of web fonts here: http://www.font2web.com/