# Segoe UI does not work properly (it works for headings only, the rest of text is displayed as Times New Roman) on Mac Safari

Tags: macos, css, fonts, safari

We have fonts defined in LESS file as follows:

```
 @base-family: Segoe UI, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 @base-family-bold: Segoe UI bold, Segoe UI, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 @base-family-semibold: Segoe UI semibold, Segoe UI, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 @base-family-light: Segoe UI Light, Segoe UI, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
```

I really don't know what to make of it. Times New Roman isn't mentioned anywhere in our LESS file and Segoe UI works perfectly fine on the rest of the browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Segoe UI might not be available on Mac. It's a paid font which is bundled with Microsoft Office 2007 and up.

See this answer for more info: 
[Will Segoe UI work on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14437881/will-segoe-ui-work-on-mac)

Comment: Thanks for an asnwer. Weird thing is, no user reported this problem before our yesterday's release. Something must have gone wrong on our part. There are two particularly weird aspects of the problem: 1. Segoe works for headings only. 2. We have set san-serif in a case our chosen fonts are not supported and Times New Roman, that replaced Segoe, is a serif typeface.

Comment: You could try to debug your webpage(F12 in windows, for Mac's Safari you need to turn on the option) and see if some css is overwriting your font settings

Comment: I resolved the issue. It was a problem within our LESS files structure. But i can confirm now, that Segoe UI, as a Microsoft font, is not available for Mac.