# Will Segoe UI font family work on iOS and Mac when using Delphi?

Tags: delphi, fonts, firemonkey, delphi-12-athens

I'm currently building an app and a website that uses the `Segoe UI` font and one of the clients is on an iPad and he just reported that the font is wrong on his iPad. After researching I discovered a [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14437881/22824066) regarding exactly this, but that question is regarding html/css and websites.

What about when using Delphi?

If I have `Segoe UI` selected as seen below:

[image: Delphi font selection]

When I run it on my Windows PC, it shows and works fine as expected. If it works on my Windows System and since I'm selecting it within my Delphi IDE and properties, does that mean it will work on all operating systems or not?

Like, I guess what I'm getting to is: Are the font I'm selecting being embedded in my EXE. Will it work on iOS and MacOS or do I need to do something specific to make sure the fonts I select in the properties will work everywhere?

Comment: "*Are the font I'm selecting being embedded in my EXE*" - no, they are accessed from the OS at runtime. You are simply configuring the name of the desired font in your UI controls, and then the RTL has to match that up when the font is used at runtime.

Comment: What happens if it can't find the font? Would my text just be invisible or default to a different font? How do I make sure it works and uses the font I am selecting in the IDE?

Comment: I don't use FireMonkey, so I can't answer that. I imagine it would just use a default font. But if you need a specific font then you will likely have to deploy it with your app, and then install/register it when needed.  FMX does have `TFontManager` and `IFMXFontManagerService` for managing fonts at runtime, as well as platform-specific `FMX.FontGlyphs.XXX` units (where `XXX` is the platform).

Comment: The OS will choose a font which it finds most similar to it. This has been like this for decades. If you want a particular font, then deploy it along with your program, just like you'd also deploy other things you can't be sure to exist at the installation target.

Comment: I recommend you should reconsider of using `Segoe UI` font in your application especially on other platforms. Why? There is a long lasting Licensing dispute about this specific font family between Microsoft and Linotype which was latter acquired by  Monotype Imaging. Ever since the mentioned Licensing dispute happened many programs that shipped with `Segoe UI` abandoned its use. I'm guessing they didn't have proper license for `Segoe UI` font distribution. You can read more about this on [Segoe UI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segoe) Wikipedia.